# “StandardIn has not been redirected” in .Net

Tags: c#, process, streamwriter

Good day!
I know about this quesion:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826884/standardin-has-not-been-redirected-error-in-net-c

But it not works to me.

So i do this: 
 1.run console app
 2. run thread in this app (start another console application) :App2
input parameters are:

```
        var ps = new ProcessStartInfo();
        ps.FileName = "something filepath";
        ps.Arguments = arrgs;
        ps.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        ps.UseShellExecute = false;
        ps.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        var p = Process.Start(ps);
```

App2 runs and do work.So,i have to close this programm correctly- set to this 2 words.

Stop this Process (App2):

```
public void Stop(int processId)
    {
            var p = Process.GetProcessById(processId);      
            using (StreamWriter sr = p.StandardInput)
            {
                sr.WriteLine("word1");
                sr.WriteLine("word2");
                sr.Close();
            }
            p.WaitForExit(10000);
            p.Close();
    }
```

But i got Exception "StandardIn has not been redirected" at line with using.
At same time, App2 stops correctly and wait for Cntrl-C or two any words (to close console).

Then,i delete this line of code:

```
using (StreamWriter sr = p.StandardInput)
            {
                sr.WriteLine("word1");
                sr.WriteLine("word2");
                sr.Close();
            }
```

And then- App2 close correctly.

So, why StreamWriter down on p.StandartInput?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm in the same trouble...
It's seems that get process 'Not catch RedirectInput value' :S

When I check pid.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput its false..

Comment: The code makes little sense.  You already have a Process reference, your `p` variable.  Why are you trying to find it back with Process.GetProcessById()?  Don't and your problems disappear.

Comment: i think,that in future i will run two or more apps and i should kill him.